# What is causing PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1722 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01722: invalid number?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo

### Fixed, see my answer.

I have a PHP script that generates dynamic SQL statements and returns the results in a format accepted by DataTables.

This morning however I have added some valid date checks which has broken the script.

PHP error reporting shows:

> **Warning**:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1722 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01722: invalid number

I have never seen this error message before. I pasted that generated SQL statement in to a SQL syntax checker which confirms that it is valid, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was using `TO_CHAR` the wrong way round.

I should have been using it on the existing column to convert that date to match the user input, and not using it to convert the user input to match the date column.

I was doing

```
select c1 from t1 where e1 between to_char(?,'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_char(?,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Should have been doing

```
select c1 from t1 where to_char(e1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') between '?' and '?'
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have invalid dates in the column auf_kopf.erfass_dat. What is the datatype of that column?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely
    auf_kopf.kunr = '63'
is faulting. auf_kopf.kunr a number? If it is, then use straight 63